# Posting Notes on Gitlab API as a 'bot' user

Tags: gitlab-api

I am developing an application that posts comments into Merge Requests on Gitlab. It works by authenticating with a given user, and then after some setup will register a webhook on the relevant project to be informed when a Merge Request update happens. When a new Merge Request is detected I want to post a comment on the Merge Request asking for some specific detail to be sent over.

However, when we post the comment on the Merge Request we can only ever seem to do it as the user that we have the OAuth token for (which of course makes sense). My question is what should we do/could we have done in order to post the note as a 'bot user' without having to register a full user into the repository? Or is this just impossible?

Comment: Currently there’s no way to do that, so the answer by @Moradnejad is your best option.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a reporter user and use its access token. The problem my arise when the user doesn't have enough access control.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a project scoped token, a bot user will automatically be created for such a token

Ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html